# GOD/JESUS - Greek - Yahuwah/Yashuah - Hebrew

Tags: names-of-god, name-of-jesus, hebrew, tetragrammaton

Growing up having a Christian background, I was taught to use God/Jesus to refer to the Creator and Son.

Recently, I've come across some information stating that our Creator has a Name and that we should use it, the name referring to Yahuah/Yahsuah, which would be in original Hebrew.

Given that Jesus was a Jew and the original text was written in ancient Hebrew, would it be fair to say that instead of the more commonly accepted Greek version of His Name, that should we use the Hebrew versions instead?

Also, if I'm misunderstanding anything in my post, I'm all ears, I'm just trying to figure out if we've been generalizing the Name and sort of not receiving the full effect of being able to state our Creators name and benefit from praising Him in that way.

This, along with knowing that throughout history, things can get sort of lost in translation as we switch from languages. On top of the knowing that devil will do whatever it takes to twist and take the opposite approach of whatever the Creator does.

> In the Bible, God declares:
>
> > I am Jehovah. That is my name; I give my glory to no one else.
> >
> > Isaiah 42:8 - NWT
>
> “Jehovah” is an English translation of the four Hebrew consonants YHWH, which constitute the divine name. That name appears some 7,000 times in the Hebrew Scriptures.  It is used more often than any title, such as “God,” “Almighty,” or “Lord,” and more frequently than any other name, such as Abraham, Moses, or David`

Comment: There might be answers [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46238/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-using-the-names-yeshua-and-yehoshua-joshua) or [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/are-there-denominations-which-prefer-using-the-name-yeshu-a-instead-of-jesus) The problem with this question is the "we should use the..." part. It makes the question impossible to answer since.  If you could say, "as a Baptist, should I use ... "  or "according to Catholic Doctrine should I..." then we might be able to concretely answer.

Comment: Ah appreciate that. I guess in general, just as any denomination, for the most part, uses God and Jesus, I'm saying should we be calling Him by His Name and not just his title?

Answer (score 7):

The Greek word, Tetragrammaton, simply means four letters. It refers to God’s holy name in the Hebrew Old Testament, namely, YHWH. As with all Hebrew words, it contains consonants only and no vowels. Thus, its pronunciation is unknown having been lost at the Babylonian captivity.

Since this word was regarded by the Jews as supremely sacred, they would not pronounce it. Therefore, a well-trained scribe would say, “Adonai” (= Lord) whenever he saw the word in the text. During the 8th and 9th centuries AD, when the Hebrew scribes started adding vowels to the Hebrew text, they used the vowels of “Adonai” for the Tetragrammaton. Thus, the Septuagint translators in about 250 BC translated the word as kyrios, Lord.

Unaware of this, the King James translators transliterated the “combination” word, “Jehovah” (only four times out of its hundreds of occurrences in the OT). However, they also adopted another tradition of translating YHWH by “LORD” – to continue the Hebrew scribal tradition.

Modern linguistic analysis has produced “Yahweh” as the best estimate of its original pronunciation.

The New Testament regularly quotes Old Testament passages containing the Tetragrammaton, and often attributes them to Jesus, especially in Hebrews, such as Heb 1:8-12, 2:12, 13, etc.

Thus, God has numerous titles including, Saviour (Isa 44:24), First and Last (Isa 41:4), "I AM" (Ex 3:13-16), Creator (Isa 44:24), the Rock (Isa 44:8), Shepherd (Ps 23), Bridegroom (Isa 49), etc.  Many of these are applied to Jesus in the NT along with more: "Son of God" and "Son of Man", "Immanuel", 'Resurrection and Life" and many more.

Comment: "As with all Hebrew words, it contains consonants only and no vowels. Thus, its pronunciation is unknown having been lost at the Babylonian captivity." How could the correct pronunciation of this one word been lost at the Babylonian captivity but the correct pronunciation of every other word been preserved for 1000+ years until a vowel system came into being?

Comment: Because only the priests knew the pronunciation of the word - it was never spoken in public.

Comment: Rather hard to believe Scriptures which could only be passed on orally could also have a "forgotten" Name, used over 6,000 times and is part of the Shema.

Comment: Scriptures were not passed on orally - the written word appears to have existed back to the time of Moses.  Even today, the Shema is recited by substituting "Adonai" for the tetragrammaton, as was almost always the case.

Comment: Don't you think Scriptures were recited every Sabbath?

Comment: That is obviously true.  However, when the priest read the scripture, each time YHWH occurs, they would pronounce "Adonai" to keep the word sacred.

Answer (score 2):

Our Creator does have a name, and it is, "I am" (אהיה *ehyeh*), which is the first person masculine form of the verb, "to be," the third person nominal form of which is, יהוה (*yeh-wah*), or "He Who is" (i.e. the Being One).

We know this from Exodus:

> **Exodus 3:1-14 (DRB)**
>
> Now Moses fed the sheep of Jethro his father in law, the priest of Madian: and he drove the flock to the inner parts of the desert, and came to the mountain of God, Horeb. 2 And the Lord appeared to him in a flame of fire out of the midst of a bush: and he saw that the bush was on fire and was not burnt. 3 And Moses said: I will go and see this great sight, why the bush is not burnt. 4 And when the Lord saw that he went forward to see, he called to him out of the midst of the bush, and said: Moses, Moses. And he answered: Here I am. 5 And he said: Come not nigh hither, put off the shoes from thy feet: for the place whereon thou standest is holy ground. 6 And he said: I am the God of thy father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob. Moses hid his face: for he durst not look at God. 7 And the Lord said to him: I have seen the affliction of my people in Egypt, and I have heard their cry because of the rigour of them that are over the works: 8 And knowing their sorrow, I am come down to deliver them out of the hands of the Egyptians, and to bring them out of that land into a good and spacious land, into a land that floweth with milk and honey, to the places of the Chanaanite, and Hethite, and Amorrhite, and Pherezite, and Hevite, and Jebusite. 9 For the cry of the children of Israel is come unto me: and I have seen their affliction, wherewith they are oppressed by the Egyptians. 10 But come, and I will send thee to Pharao, that thou mayst bring forth my people, the children of Israel out of Egypt.
>
> 11 And Moses said to God: Who am I that I should go to Pharao, and should bring forth the children of Israel out of Egypt? 12 And he said to him: I will be with thee: and this thou shalt have for a sign, that I have sent thee: When thou shalt have brought my people out of Egypt, thou shalt offer sacrifice to God upon this mountain. 13 Moses said to God: Lo, I shall go to the children of Israel, and say to them: The God of your fathers hath sent me to you. **If they should say to me: What is his name? what shall I say to them?** 14 God said to Moses: I AM WHO AM [ אהיה אשר אהיה ]. He said: Thus shalt thou say to the children of Israel: [I AM] [אהיה] hath sent me to you.

In the pre-Christian Greek Bible, they use a convention still used today, and that is to translate יהוה as simply "Lᴏʀᴅ" (in Greek κυριος *kyrios*), a convention also used in the New Testament (which was written in Koine Greek, not Hebrew).<sup>1</sup>

The main 'creed' of ancient Judaism, often called the *Shma'* (from its first word in Hebrew) reads: "Hear, O Israel: The Lᴏʀᴅ [יהוה] is our God; the Lᴏʀᴅ [יהוה] is one." (*Deuteronomy 6:4*).

You may be confusing the name of Jesus with this name identified as 'the name of God' in the Old Testament, since they are similar in Hebrew. Namely (no pun intended), you may be confusing Yahweh and Yeshua.

A proof simultaneiously that Matthew was written in Hebrew originally,<sup>2</sup> and that Jesus' name in Hebrew is Yeshua is found in Matthew 1, where we see a classic Hebrew name etymology:<sup>3</sup>

> **Matthew 1:20-21 (DRB)** But while he thought on these things, behold the angel of the Lord appeared to him in his sleep, saying: Joseph, son of David, fear not to take unto thee Mary thy wife, for that which is conceived in her, is of the Holy Ghost. 21 And she shall bring forth a son: and thou shalt call his name **JESUS [*yeshua*]**. For **he shall save [*yoshia*]** his people from their sins.

(To be clear, Matthew exists only in its Greek version, but when we translate it 'back'—to beg the question—into Hebrew, we can see certain Hebrew words and phrases that are quite obviously Hebrew in origin, i.e. evidence a Hebrew version, not simply a Hebraic style of writing.)

Yeshua therefore means 'Saviour.'

*Yahweh* or *the Lᴏʀᴅ* *was never intended to be confused with* the name Yeshua or Jesus—both of which are just the Hebrew and English form of the respective names, not different names (like *Yechezkel* and Ezekiel, *Mosheh* and Moses, etc.). One refers to the Divine Nature, and the other refers to the man born of Mary, who although personally God, the Word (John 1:1; 14) nonetheless became complete and true man, with His own name given to Him at birth. And an apt name, "for he shall save His people from their sins" (a role which could in any case only be given to a Divine One, since this is the prerogative of God alone in the Old Testament).

Jesus is called both Lord and Jesus, and often both in the New Testament. What is important is that we recognize that He is both "Lord and God" (Mk. 1:3; Jn. 20:27-28), God and man. So if we refer to Him as "the First and the Last," (Rev. 1:17-18) or "Jesus," (Mt. 1:21) both describe Him accurately.

---

### <sup>Footnotes</sup>

<sup>1 This is the consistent testimony of Christians since the earliest days (with the notable exception of Matthew, which is claimed to have been written in both a Hebrew and Greek version—the Hebrew version of which is no longer extant), as well as the unanimous opinion of New Testament scholars. One who is fluent in Koine or Hebrew, or both, will rather readily be able to discern whether a work is a Greek original or a translation into Greek; the New Testament is unanimously acknowledged to have been authored in Koine Greek, and not Hebrew.</sup>

<sup>2 See also, e.g., Mt. 3:9: "for God is able even of these **stones [*abanim*]** to raise up **children [*benim*]** unto Abraham."</sup>

<sup>3 I.e. Gn. 4:1: " And Adam knew his wife Eve, and she concieved and gave birth to **Cain [*Qain*]**, saying: **I have acquired [*qanithi*]** a man by the Lᴏʀᴅ." Cain, therefore, essentially means, "Acquired."</sup>

Comment: Really appreciate that explanation. I think the main thing for me is, if I can refer to Them (God, Jesus) as Yahweh or Yahuah and Yeshua or Yashuah respectively,  then I would like to call Him by His Name directly. Calling someone by their name would be key in any relationship,  in my opinion.

Comment: So, would you say that it really doesn't matter how/how you refer to Him just as long as you know that it is Him and Him only?

Comment: And btw, I upvoted but am a noob so you wont see it I don think, not sure why someone downvoted this

Comment: Great explanation, so calling Jesus by the Hebrew word Yahweh is not in the scriptures as you put the scripture reference Matthew1:20-21. Jesus in Hebrew is Yeshua not Yahweh is that correct?

Comment: It makes me sad that the person who downvoted this answer did not make clear why. Personally I learned a lot from this answer.

Comment: @mph85 Yahweh always refers to the Divinity. The Divine Nature. God. Jesus, Yeshua, does not, but is the name given to the incarnate Son (whereas He is both as the incarnate Son). As such, we can refer to Jesus as either, but cannot **conflate** them: they are two names which apply equally to the Son only. The practice of the Church is to call Jesus 'Jesus.' In the New Testament, they use 'Lord' where perhaps the Hebrew 'Yahweh' would have been in the Old Testament, so we simply do not discontinue the convention: we know the referent of 'the Lord' is "the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob."

Comment: @marianagustin It's correct that Yeshua is Jesus in Hebrew. It derives from the root verb 'to save.'' Yahweh is the name of God in Hebrew as He gave it to Moses, and comes from the root verb, 'to be.' However, in Hebrew thought, a name wasn't the letters or pronunciation of the name 'Yahweh' or 'Yeshua.' After all, the criminal crucified with Jesus also had the name 'Yeshua' (Yeshua bar-Abba) It wasn't a brand new name in Jesus' day. It just describes Him actually and really, and actually only. It referred solely to the identity the name conveyed.

Comment: E.g. we aren't saved by the Yeshua BarAbba, yet "there is no other name under heaven" by which we are saved than 'Yeshua.' As you see, it refers to the identity and mission and person of the Saviour, not the letters ישוע.

Comment: "Our Creator does have a name, and it is, "I am" (אהיה ehyeh)" I think this goes beyond the Biblical evidence. By Exodus 3:14 you could only say that his name is "I am who I am". YHWH appears to be a related word, but not in any straightforward manner. That's why we still write YHWH or Yahweh rather than translating it to "He-Who-Is" or something like that.

Comment: God says, "I am the one who is," or "I am who am," so tell the children of Israel, "I am" has sent you. In the next verse this is, Tell the sons of Israel יהוה the God of your fathers has sent me to you. It's pretty straightforward: יהוה is the third person nominal form of His name. To say יהוה and אהיה aren't directly related is the height of ridiculousness in my opinion.

Comment: But if his name is אהיה, then why is it so rare? Why is יהוה so much more common? Or is יהוה his name? Then why doesn't he say יהוה in Ex 3:14?

Comment: I didn't say His name was אהיה—*He did*. יהוה is clearly the third person nominal form of the "I am" which He alone can say of Himself (when the focus is on the verb 'To be,' apparently only when speaking about His name specifically; other times when He uses יהוה He is referring to His name as being such—The One Who is). This is my view on the matter. But that He said, 'My name is אהיה' is not; and as I noted, 'My name is יהוה' is conflated and equated with 'My name is אהיה.'

Answer (score 2):

Before dealing with the main subject, we must note that Jehovah is a *flatly wrong* English translation of the revealed divine Name. To support this statement, I must deal with two issues: the history of Tetragrammaton use by Post-Exilic Jews and the history of Hebrew writing.

Regarding the first issue, after ca. 300 BC Jews started to avoid pronouncing the Tetragrammaton, first restricting its use to priests in the daily liturgy, then, probably after the death of Simeon the Righteous ca. 200 BC, further restricting its use to only the High Priest in the yearly Yom Kippur liturgy, and finally, after the destruction of the Second Temple in 70 AD, ceasing to pronounce it all. Thus, when reading aloud a Scripture passage in a religious service, any occurrence of YHWH in the text was replaced by "Adonai" (Lord) or, if it was immediately preceded by "Adonai" in the text, by "Elohim" (God).

Regarding the second issue, Hebrew writing was originally purely consonantal, so that the context of a word indicated its vocalization. Starting in the 6th century AD, the Masoretes added diacritical signs (niqqud) to the consonantal text to denote vowels. But in a few cases, the vowels denoted by the niqqud are not those of the word written in the text (the ketiv = "[what is] written") but those of the word to be read in its place (the qere = "[what is] read") [1]. The Tetragrammaton is one of those cases, so that the vowels added to YWHW are those of "Adonai" (in most cases) or of "Elohim".

Now, if someone who ignores all this reads a Hebrew Bible, he may think that the vowels added to YHWH are those that pertain to it, and conclude that the divine Name is Jehovah. But that conclusion would be flatly wrong.

Having cleared this preliminary issue, we can now ask "Why don't Christians address God by the Name YHWH (whatever its right vocals are)?" The obvious answer to this question is "Because Jesus never addressed God by the Name YWHW", which in turn leads to the question "Why did Jesus never address God by the Name YHWH?", which has already been asked and answered in this site, including by me [2]. For the sake of completeness, I will give a somewhat reworked version of that answer below.

First of all, let us recall two statements at the beginning and end of Jesus' High Priestly Prayer which make it clear that, for Jesus, making known to us the Name of God was a matter of prime importance:

> "**I revealed your Name** to the men whom You have given Me out of the
>   world." (Jn 17:6)
>
> "And **I made known to them your Name, and will make it known,** so
>   that the Love with which You loved Me may be in them, and I in them."
>   (Jn 17:26)

Since Jesus referred to God as his Father or "the Father", and the Apostles in their Epistles referred to God as "God the Father" or, in longer words, as "God, the Father of our Lord Jesus Christ", **if we assume that the Apostles received correctly Jesus' revelation of God's Name**, then "God the Father", understood as "God the Father of a consubstantial Son", is the fullness of the Name YHWH, just as Jesus' New Law is the fullness of Mosaic Law.

But now we may ask: **in what sense is the Name "God the Father" the fullness of the Name YHWH?** To answer that, we must recall that two divine Names were revealed to Moses in the burning bush, a Name in the first person, "Ehyeh" = "I Am", in Ex 3:14 (which Jesus applied to Himself in Jn 8:24,28,58 and Jn 13:19) and a Name in the third person, "YHWH", in Ex 3:15.

Now, whereas the Masoretic text provides the vowels of the first Name, so that its meaning of qal (simple) stem, first person, singular, imperfect form, of the verb "hyh" = "to be", i.e. "I Am", is unequivocal, it does not provide the vowels of the second Name, so that in principle it can be either the qal stem "Yihweh" = "He Is" or the hifil (causative) stem "Yahweh" = "He causes to be" [3] [4]. The second option is supported by three facts:

a. Teophoric names of people (e.g. Netanyahu) and places, plus the shorter form of the name, Yah, have "a" and not "i".

b. The causative meaning implies the qal, since only Subsistent, Absolute Being can cause contingent beings to be, i.e. create them and sustain them in existence.

c. While the first Name expresses Who each divine Person Is [5] **in Himself**, Subsistent, Absolute Being (as Unbegotten, Begotten and Spirated respectively), the second Name in the causative meaning expresses Who each divine Person, and the three Persons altogether as one efficient cause, is **for creatures**: the Creator and Sustainer, He Who causes creatures to be.

Now, since creating, causing creatures to be, is not something that God did by necessity of nature but something that He freely decided to do, the Name Yahweh, in contrast to Ehyeh, **does not express Who God Is in Himself but only from the viewpoint of creatures.** (For whom that sense of the Name in the third person is essential, because if God had not created there would be no creature to pronounce his Name in the third person. So for God's Name in the third person to be pronounced, God must create and therefore be, from the viewpoint of creatures, "He causes to be".)

Bringing now into play Jesus' revelation that God as First [6], the First divine Person, begets/generates eternally a consubstantial Son and therefore is "God the Father", we can immediately perceive this parallel:

**YHWH** = **He causes** (contingent creatures) **to be** (contingent sense), by an act of free will.

**Father** = **He generates** (one consubstantial Son) **to Be** (subsistent sense), by nature.

whereby we can immediately understand that the Name "God the Father" is an infinitely fuller version of the Name Yahweh, as the generation of a consubstantial Son, Who Is **all that God the Father Is** (except Father), is an infinitely higher act than the creation of contingent creatures, each of which participates in a limited, finite way the divine fullness of Being.

To note, we do not say that God the Father "causes his consubstantial Son to Be" (whereby the parallelism would be even greater) because the "narrow" sense of the Latin word "causa" denotes difference of substance between cause and effect, but we could even say that if we used "cause" in the "broad" sense of the Greek word "aitia", which can also stand, and in this case would stand, for the sense of the Latin word "principium", denoting numerical sameness of substance between begetter/generator and begotten/generated [7].

Importantly, both divine Names have their respective professions of faith in Scripture. For the Name YHWH, it is the Shema in Deut 6:4:

> "YHWH Eloheinu, YHWH Echad." = "**YHWH our God, YHWH is One**."

For the Name God the Father, which implies God the Son, it is the profession of faith in 1 Cor 8:6, whose parallelism with the Shema becomes more evident if we italicize the (reasonably added) words that are not in the Greek text [8], as I did below:

> "**to us** *there is* **one God the Father**, of Whom *are* all things, and we
>   for Him; and one Lord, Jesus Christ, by Whom *are* all things, and we
>   through Him."

Thus, Jesus, by revealing Himself as "I Am" (Jn 8:24,28,58; Jn 13:19), one with the Father (Jn 10:30), simultaneously reveals that God is not only "He causes (limited creatures) to be" contingently ad extra, but first and foremost "He generates (a consubstantial Son)" esentially ad intra. God as First, the First Person, is by nature both "I Am" and "Father", the begetter of a consubstantial Son. Thus, "Father" from the viewpoint of Jesus, and "God the Father" from our viewpoint, is an infinitely fuller version of the Name Yahweh.

In addition, just as the Name Yahweh presupposes the Name Ehyeh, "I Am", because no contingent being but only the Subsistent, Absolute Being can cause contingent beings to be, i.e. create them and sustain them in existence, the Name God the Father, understood in the orthodox sense of "God the Father of a consubstantial Son", presupposes the Name "I Am", because no contingent subject but only the Subsistent Being as First, the First Subsistent Hypostasis, can beget a consubstantial Son, i.e. a Son who is numerically the same substance (understood in a particular, not a universal sense) as the Begetter.

Finally, in addition to revealing Who God Is in Himself, the Father that by nature generates eternally a consubstantial Son, Jesus has revealed that God the Father has decreed to make us his adoptive sons, not just in name but in fact (1 Jn 3:1), by making us partakers of his consubstantial Son (Heb 3:14) by grace, i.e. by transforming us in the image of, and uniting us to, his Son. Thus, Jesus has revealed that God is, **for us**, not only YHWH, "He causes (us) to be (creatures)" by creating our nature, but also "Abba", "Father", "He causes (us) to be his adoptive sons in his only consubstantial Son" by infusing us with his grace. Since what God causes us to be by his grace, i.e. his adoptive sons in his only Son, is a reality infinitely higher than what he causes us to be by our nature, i.e. his creatures, the Name "Father" is, **for us**, an infinitely fuller version of the Name YHWH.

Moreover, Jesus revealed also that the reason for this infinitely better supernatural new creation is that God the Father loved us even as He loved his Son (Jn 17:23), which was clearly demonstrated by the infinite cost that God willed to bear to carry out that new creation, namely the passion and death of his Son in his assumed human nature. Thus there are two reasons why Father is, **for us**, an infinitely fuller version of the divine Name: the infinitely better supernatural new creation that it refers to, and the infinitely greater love for us that said new creation shows, both by itself and by its cost.

**References and notes**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qere_and_Ketiv

[2] [Why did Jesus never address God by the name "Jehovah"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/why-did-jesus-never-address-god-by-the-name-jehovah/)

[3] http://drmsh.com/the-naked-bible/yhwh/

[4] https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/31734/15789

[5] I usually capitalize the verb "to be" when it denotes Subsistent Being.

[6] When speaking of God the Father, the terms "First" and "Firstness" ("Primitas" in latin) are **not** meant in a temporal sense, since both the generation of the Son and the spiration of the Holy Spirit are eternal.

[7] The different scopes of meaning of Latin "causa" and Greek "aitia" are most evident in the bull "Laetentur Caeli" from the (Roman Catholic) Ecumenical Council of Florence, when it says: "thereby also the Son should be signified, according to the Greeks indeed as cause, and according to the Latins as principle of the subsistence of the Holy Spirit, just like the Father."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laetentur_Caeli

[8] https://biblehub.com/text/1_corinthians/8-6.htm

**Note to Roman Catholics**: The last part of this answer follows the Franciscan theological tradition in trinitarian theology, whose main line is Greek Fathers - Richard of Saint Victor - Alexander of Hales - St. Bonaventure, and which posits an emanation account of the distinction between the Persons and understands the Father's innascibility in a positive way as Firstness, thus holding a pre-relational notion of God the Father (i.e. it is because He is First that He begets and thus is Father). Those following the Dominican theological tradition in trinitarian theology, particularly Thomists, will disagree with that.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if anyone will read this, but this is what I know about the names of God.

YHWH is the unspoken Hebrew personal name of God in the Old Testament.  There are many names of God, 8 of them being the Covenant names of God as to the blessings that are provided to the children of God who believe in Christ’s sacrifice for their sins.  His blood upon the door posts of your heart, the circumcision of the heart performed without human hands, but by faith alone is what brings you into Covenant with God.  God made the Covenant without our help, we simply put our faith in his work on Calvary.

Jehovah is a word that humans understood as the word Lord, whether applied to Christ or human rulers that believed they were god.  Caesar applied the Hebrew word Jehovah to himself as Lord, he believed he was deity.  Jehovah is a title rather than a name.

The 8 Covenant names of God are these:

- Jehovah Tsidkenu (the Lord my Righteousness-salvation)
- Jehovah Makeddeshkim (the Lord my sanctification)
- Jehovah Shalom (the Lord my peace-atonement)
- Jehovah Rapha (the Lord my healer)
- Jehovah Jireh (the Lord my provider-of the sacrifice)
- Jehovah Shammah (the Lord is here)
- Jehovah Nissi (the Lord my Victory)
- Jehovah Ro Hi (the Lord my Shepherd)

These names explain Why God refers to himself as “I am” he is all that we need, everything, and we are to look to him alone for all that we need. When you get saved, the world will no longer provide for you.  It’s Gods job to provide for you, just like he did in the Exodus wilderness.

There are some other names:

- Elohim, which means the plural godhead trinity.
- El Olam, God Everlasting
- El Elyon, God Most High, the Most High God
- El Shaddai, God Almighty
- Abraham knew him as Elohim
- Moses new him as Jehovah...
- David knew him by his Covenant names in the psalms.
- We know him as Jesus.

Jesus comes from the Greek translation of his name.
In Jesus time, the people spoke Aramaic and koine Greek.  The aristocratic Jews and priests spoke High Greek.  Hebrew was the ceremonial language of the synagogue and Temple and home rituals.

The Bible writes the name of God in the Old Testament using all caps, LORD.  In all caps, the reference is to YHWH or one of the Covenant names.  You need to get eSword if you want an app that can show you the Hebrew with the Greek and English.

Around 165BC the entirety of the Old Testament had been translated into Greek, in Alexandria, and the Hebrews in Israel used the Greek versions also in the synagogues.  There were synagogues everywhere.  A synagogue was required when their were 10 Jewish families in a particular area.  God had planned to turn them all into Christian churches if they would come to Christ and believe, then the Romans would not have cared about Christian worship, because Judaism was a legal religion.  If they had believed the world aroma. World would have been Christian overnight almost, but instead the Judiazers persecuted Paul’s gospel.  By the year 300 there were approximately 60 million Christians living throughout Europe.  God outdid the Jews with his miracle power up through about 500AD when Mary worship strove against the spirit and the true faith was persecuted.

Psalm 23 in the Hebrew contains the names of God.

The Hebrew letters mean “Behold the hand, Behold the nail”. YHWH is our salvation.

- Yud. (A hand)
- Heh. (Behold)
- Waw. (A nail)
- Heh. (Behold)

So you can see by not allowing the people to speak the name or read the text, they would not know who their savior was when he came.  But Zechariah says they will look upon him and ask about the nail prints in his hands.

Answer (score -1):

**The name of Jesus in Hebrew word is "Yeshua" and " Iēsous" in Greek.**

> Jesus (IPA: /ˈdʒiːzəs/) is a masculine given name derived from the name Iēsous (Greek: Ἰησοῦς), the Greek form of the Hebrew name Yeshua (Hebrew: ישוע‎).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jFka.png)[2] As its roots lie in the name Yeshua, it is etymologically related to another biblical name, Joshua. "Jesus" is usually not used as a given name in the English-speaking world, while its counterparts have had longstanding popularity among people with other language backgrounds, such as the Spanish Jesús or the Arabic Isa.
>
> The name Jesus is derived from the Hebrew name Yeshua, which is based on the Semitic root y-š-ʕ (Hebrew: ישע‎), meaning "to deliver; to rescue."[3][4][5] Yeshua, and its longer form, Yehoshua, were both in common use by Jews during the Second Temple period and many Jewish religious figures bear the name, notably Jesus in the New Testament, and Joshua in the Hebrew Bible.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jFka.png)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_(name)

**While the word GOD in Hebrew is "(YHWH יהוה)" and in Greek "Kyrios"**

> The name of God most often used in the Hebrew Bible is the Tetragrammaton (YHWH יהוה). It is frequently anglicized as Jehovah and Yahweh and written in most English editions of the Bible as "the Lord" owing to the Jewish tradition increasingly viewing the divine name as too sacred to be uttered. It was thus replaced vocally in the synagogue ritual by the Hebrew word Adonai (“My Lords”), which was translated as Kyrios (“Lord”) in the Septuagint, the Greek version of the Hebrew scriptures.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jFka.png)
>
> Rabbinic Judaism describes seven names which are so holy that, once written, should not be erased: YHWH and six others which can be categorized as titles are El ("God"), Eloah ("God"), Elohim ("Gods"), Shaddai (“Almighty"), Ehyeh (“I Will Be”), and Tzevaot ("[of] Hosts").[2] Other names are considered mere epithets or titles reflecting different aspects of God,[3] but chumrah sometimes dictates special care such as the writing of "G-d" instead of "God" in English or saying Ṭēt-Vav (טו, lit. "9-6") instead of Yōd-Hē (יה, lit. "10-5" but also "Jah") for the number fifteen in Hebrew.[4]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Judaism

*Given that Jesus was a Jew and the original text was written in ancient Hebrew, would it be fair to say that instead of the more commonly accepted Greek version of His Name, that should we use the Hebrew versions instead?*

And you support your question with this scripture ***"In the Bible, God declares: “I am Jehovah. That is my name; I give my glory to no one else.” (Isaiah 42:8)***

You might consider the New Testament to have a better picture of this verse;

> **Jesus Prays to Be Glorified**
>
> 17 After Jesus said this, he looked toward heaven and prayed:
>
> “Father, the hour has come. Glorify your Son, that your Son may glorify you. 2 For you granted him authority over all people that he might give eternal life to all those you have given him. 3 Now this is eternal life: that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you have sent. 4 I have brought you glory on earth by finishing the work you gave me to do. 5 And now, Father, glorify me in your presence with the glory I had with you before the world began." (John17:1-5)
>
> "Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Me." (Matthew28:18)
>
> **Philippians 2:9-15 New International Version (NIV)**
>
> 9 Therefore God exalted him to the highest place
>       and gave him the name that is above every name,
>   10 that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow,
>       in heaven and on earth and under the earth,
>   11 and every tongue acknowledge that Jesus Christ is Lord,
>       to the glory of God the Father.

**Did God the Father and Creator "glorify" His Son Jesus Christ? Yes.**

Now, let's take a closer look at your desire to worship God with the original Hebrew word that is according to your statement is;

> ***"the name referring to Yahuah/Yahsuah, which would be in original Hebrew."***

If the name **"Jesus"** was already proclaimed here on earth and also bound in heaven as the **"the name above all names"** why would it be much better or biblical to give praise or glory to God in original Hebrew word?

As the doubting Thomas one of the Apostle of Jesus after seeing the ***glorified Jesus Christ*** had said and professed by faith ***"My Lord and My God".***

> **Jesus Appears to Thomas**
>   …27Then Jesus said to Thomas, “Put your finger here and look at My hands. Reach out your hand and put it into My side. Stop doubting and believe.” 28Thomas replied, “My Lord and my God!” (John20:27-28)

Lastly, to focus on the Hebrew word YHWH or YHVH, this word does not pertains to a name but it is a description of how God intend to offer salvation to mankind. The Hebrew word Yahweh, YHWH or YHVH is not a name but a description.

The Hebrew word YHWH is not a name but a description. You cannot pronounced the Hebrew word YHWH pertaining to the Name of God. Moses was given a scene in the burning bush a man crucified.

> Although in the English language the term onomatopoeia means "the imitation of a sound", the compound word onomatopoeia (ὀνοματοποιία) in the Greek language means "making or creating names". For words that imitate sounds, the term ὴχομιμητικό (echomimetico) or echomimetic) is used. Onomatopoeia - Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia

The word YHWH is the origin why a God given name had a meaning or a mission attached to it. Starting from Jesus Christ, Mary and Prophets and Patriarchs and Old Testament names had a corresponding meaning and mission that defines the life of the bearer of the name.

**YHWH tetragammanton means "Behold the Hand, Behold the Nails".**

This means, Moses was able to see the pre-figurement of Jesus at the Foot of the Cross as the means of God Salvation. They are pronounced, in Hebrew, **"Yod Hey Vav Hey,"** when you read them in the Hebrew manner from right to left.

> The four letters in God's name in Hebrew have the following meanings:
>
> Hey = Behold
>
> Vav = Nail
>
> Yod = Closed Hand

When read in English from left to right, it says:

> **"BEHOLD THE NAIL, BEHOLD THE HAND!" Or, "Behold the nailed hand."**[image]

http://the-kingdom-of-god-is-within-you.blogspot.com/2012/02/behold-nail-behold-hand-exodus-314-this.html

We will be suprise if we will discover the greatest mystery behind the Hebrew word YHWH is the word ***"BEHOLD"***

***"Behold means to gaze"***. *and Moses was given the chance to BEHOLD that Man Crucified at the Cross.*

Jesus at the Foot of the Cross uttered the word **"BEHOLD"** to the Woman and to St.John the beloved Apostles.

> "When Jesus saw his mother and the disciple there whom he loved, he said to his mother, “Woman, **behold, your son**.” Then he said to the disciple, “**Behold, your mother**.” And from that hour the disciple took her into his home."(John19"26-27)

God commanded Moses to ***"BEHOLD"*** and Jesus commanded the Woman to ***"BEHOLD"***.We either represents St.John or the other Mary's and we too are commanded by Jesus to ***"BEHOLD"*** His sacrifice "At the Foot of the Cross". But we can only ***"BEHOLD"*** the Crucified Christ and understand the meaning of the Cross of Christ if each one of us welcome Mary in our home, meaning allowing Mary to be our own Mother too as the greatest gift of Jesus Christ to all of us.

Comment: Down voting for the pseudo-linguistics of trying to derive meaning from the individual letters of YHWH.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not trying to derive meaning of individual Hebrew letters but added it as explanation to better grasp why it's not a name. I'd link the reference who expounded the meaning of the word YHVH or YHWH. And added another link to Moses seeing a "Crucified Man".